# divide two numbers get result throw that result how i get again divided value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$a=10;$b=3;
$c=$a/$b;
echo $c;
3.33333333
$d=$c+$c+$c=9
```

but i need

```
$d=4+3+3; $d=10;
```

how can i get again `$a` value in `$d` throw `$c` by `sum of $b` times?

Comment: Show your code. This one works as expected. http://3v4l.org/F7bWp

Comment: $tot_qus = $this->input->post('totalquestion');
$main_cat = $this->input->post('maincategory');
$cnt_main_cat=count($main_cat);
$each_qus=$tot_qus/$cnt_main_cat;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = 10;
$number = 3;

$result = array_fill(0, $number, intval(floor($value / $number))); 
// create new array of values
if ($value % $number) // if you need extra values
    {
    $rest_value = array_fill(0, $value % $number, 1);

    $result = array_map(function($value1, $value2)
        { return $value1 + $value2; }, $result, $rest_value);
    }
var_dump($result);

// array(3) {
//   [0] =>
//   int(4)
//   [1] =>
//   int(3)
//   [2] =>
//   int(3)
// }
```